# ServiceStack, OrmLite Issue Saving Related Entities

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I've searched for a while looking for a solution to this problem and haven't found anything.

I'm trying to POST a Client DTO and it's related Contacts DTOs to my ServiceStack web service but I'm getting an error.  I've followed along with the OrmLite tests located [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/LoadReferencesTests.cs).

My DTOs:

```
public partial class Client {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
    public string HomePhoneAreaCode { get; set; }
    public string HomePhoneExchange { get; set; }
    public string HomePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string HomeFaxAreaCode { get; set; }
    public string HomeFaxExchange { get; set; }
    public string HomeFaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string KeyNumber { get; set; }
    public string AlarmCode { get; set; }
    public string GarageDoorCode { get; set; }
    public string MyAPCUsername { get; set; }
    public string MyAPCPassword { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public partial class Contact {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhoneAreaCode { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhoneExchange { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhoneAreaCode { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhoneExchange { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool CanSMS { get; set; }
    public string PersonalEmail { get; set; }
    public string WorkEmail { get; set; }
    public string AlternateEmail { get; set; }
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

In my Service:

```
    public int Post(Client client) {
        Db.Save(client, references: true);

        return client.ID;
    }
```

And my test code:

```
var newClient = new Client {
    Street = "1234 Any Avenue",
    City = "Gorham",
    State = "ME",
    ZipCode = "22222",
    HomePhoneAreaCode = "123",
    HomePhoneExchange = "456",
    HomePhoneNumber = "7890",
    HomeFaxAreaCode = "098",
    HomeFaxExchange = "765",
    HomeFaxNumber = "4321",
    KeyNumber = "99",
    AlarmCode = "1234",
    GarageDoorCode = "abcd",
    IsActive = true,
    Notes = "These are the notes for the new client.",

    Contacts = new List<Contact>() {
        new Contact { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", PersonalEmail = "john.doe@gmail.com", CanSMS = true, Ordinal = 1 },
        new Contact { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smith", PersonalEmail = "jane.smith@gmail.com", CanSMS = false, Ordinal = 2 }
    },
};


// POST entity 
int newClientID = serviceClient.Post<int>(newClient);
```

The last line produces the error - 
WebServiceException, message "Cant find 'ClientId' Property on Type 'Contact'"

I've tried different combinations of the Reference, References, and ForeignKey attributes to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: **Edit - Some additional information...**
    In the service, this code works:
    `Db.Save(client);`
   but this throws the same error:
   `Db.Save(client);  Db.SaveReferences(client, client.Contacts);`

Comment: Use `Id` instead of `ID`.

Comment: OK, that worked but I have one more issue - There are several Reference DTOs on my Client DTO (omitted for brevity).  For example, I showed the List<Contact> but there is also a List<EmergencyContact>.  If I don't add any Emergency Contacts, `Db.Save(client, references: true)` throws a NullReferenceException.  Should I have to check each reference DTO and only call `Db.SaveReferences(client, client.EmergencyContacts)` if it's not NULL?

Comment: That was a bug that's now [fixed in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/c9bdf795b40da8ff06167ae2798c7c8ed889e36f) available in the next v4.0.21 release

Comment: Great!  Do you have an ETA on the release of 4.0.21?

Comment: Aiming for next week but no guarantees. Join the [ServiceStack G+ Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/112445368900682590445) to be notified of new release announcements.

Comment: BTW, ServiceStack kicks A$$!  Got my boss to get Business licenses for all the devs at our firm!

Comment: Awesome to hear, appreciated :). BTW this fix is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).